# How do I stop this error when using backspace in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I am using a TextBox, but then delete the text and press backspace when there are no characters left, I get the error

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

This happens during this code

```cs
if (cb_type.Text == "Deposit")
{
    if (double.Parse(txt_amount.Text) > double.Parse(Global.Allowance))
    {
        txt_amount.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        btn_submit.Enabled = false;
        lbl_amount.Text = "Amount Exceeds Allowance Left";
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_amount.Text = "Amount:";
        txt_amount.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btn_submit.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Use `decimal.TryParse()`. A null/empty string is not a valid value. -- You should always use the `.TryParse()` version when the input comes from the UI. -- Kind of weird that you have to do this: `double.Parse(Global.Allowance)`.

Comment: `double.Parse("")` will throw `System.FormatException` by design because the empty string does not represent a number. The [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0) suggests that we call `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check if a string is empty. You can either catch the exception with a try block or preferably use `decimal.TryParse` (prefer `decimal` over `double` for currency types) PS:  "why" questions are hard.  We can tell you "what", but less so "why" when it comes to the minds of the creators of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your input field has a value before you try to use the value.

```
if(cb_type.Text == "Deposit" && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_amount.Text))
{
    // do some stuff...
}
```

... and if you have a value... do as @jimi suggests and use `TryParse`.